# Certbot Can't Generate SSL Certificates Due to Challange Falure?

Tags: server, apache2

I've run `sudo certbot --apache -d scilabnet.asuscomm.com` but I get the error when trying to set up SSL certificates on my apache2 server:

```
sarah@scilab_comp_0:~$ sudo certbot --apache -d scilabnet.asuscomm.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for scilabnet.asuscomm.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. scilabnet.asuscomm.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http://scilabnet.asuscomm.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/6Tj8Rc9c6D_aZ_lqPdtXXKqfdubVAWn8Gapl5ZA6-jc: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: scilabnet.asuscomm.com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Fetching
   http://scilabnet.asuscomm.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/6Tj8Rc9c6D_aZ_lqPdtXXKqfdubVAWn8Gapl5ZA6-jc:
   Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

I'm following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. UFW isn't enabled.

How can I get SSL certificates working on my apache2 server?

**EDIT 0:** The domain is accessible (And was during the test):
[image: Default Page]

The server is set to listen to port 80 usigng `ports.conf`

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT 1:** The server has a static IP of 192.168.1.222
Router Configuration:
[image: DMZ]

**EDIT 2:**
iptables:

```
sarah@scilab_comp_0:~$ sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1278 packets, 123K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1333 72435 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    5   300 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
    2   120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1041 packets, 71711 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1234 63983 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 ctstate ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 ctstate ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443 ctstate ESTABLISHED
```

**EDIT 3:** According to my router, the domain *should* be registered. I registered the domain on the router software itself, and it told me that it *was* registered:
[image: DDNS]
[image: DDNS 2]

**EDIT 4:** Changed the DMZ Settings to Disabled and set the ports 80, 443 to forward to the server (192.168.1.222).

I noticed when I ran `sudo service apache2 status` that it has an error that it can't resolve the fully qualified name. Not sure where that is going wrong or if that is contributing, but I'll post my configuration:

Virtual host for the website:
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/scilabnet.asuscomm.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin SarahSzabo@Protonmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/scilabnet.asuscomm.com/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ServerName scilabnet.asuscomm.com
        ServerAlias www.scilabnet.asuscomm.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The site is enabled. I can't reach it through the URL, but i can reach it using `192.168.1.222` in the browser's URL bar. I get the website's index file.

My website's index is at: `/var/www/html/scilabnet.asuscomm.com/public_html/index.html`.

**EDIT 5:** Port Forwarding
[image: Port Forwarding]

**EDIT 6:** Proper Port Forwarding:
[image: Proper Port Forwarding]

Comment: I am getting IP of 69.125.122.255  Is the server exposed directly to the internet to allow traffic from external to come in?  If this server is behind a router is port forwarding of port 80 setup for internal?

Comment: @Terrance The router is set up to forward all ports to the server. The router has the IP of the server as a DMZ. It should be exposed to the internet.

Comment: A nmap scan of that IP address has returned that ports 20, 21, 25, 80, 135, 139, 1080, 3128, 5431 and 8080 are all filtered.  From the nmap site:  "Nmap cannot determine whether the port is open because packet filtering prevents its probes from reaching the port. The filtering could be from a dedicated firewall device, router rules, or host-based firewall software."  This is why you are getting your failure.  You need to check all of your internal connections to this host.  I guess there could be a possibility that the ISP could be blocking too.

Comment: @Terrance UFW is offline, I think no firewall is applied when the server is in the router's DMZ state, and I have no dedicated firewall device.

Comment: iptables could still be running on the host.  See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands

Comment: @Terrance I've never used iptables. Does that mean that it could still be running in the background?

Comment: Yes, it sure can.  Try running `sudo iptables -nvL` and it should list all rules, etc.

Comment: @Terrance I posted the iptables command. I've got to go to sleep though. It's really early here.

Comment: @SarahSzabo, the output of  `whois scilabnet.asuscomm.com` shows to me your domain is not registered!? You should have a registered domain that points to your public IP. Also I do not think you should use **DMZ**, user **Virtual Server / Port Forwarding** and forward just only the ports that you need (80,433 and maybe 22).

Comment: @Terrance I posted pics of the registration process on the router software. According to it, (And it's linked service) it should be registered. Also, when I go to `scilabnet.asuscomm.com` it takes me to the local version of the apache software.

Comment: That was pa4080 that asked you about the registration.  It is taking you to the local scilabnet.asuscomm.com because on your system that is how you have it defined in your hosts file.  I do have to agree that is would be better to put your host out of the DMZ and use port forwarding of the router to the host instead so that connections to specific ports know where to go.  There is a chance that since your computer is in the DMZ the router doesn't know where to send the traffic to.

Comment: @Terrance I disabled the DMZ and now I can't see the local version of the server from another computer by using the website name. I can reach it by entering `192.168.1.222` though.

Comment: Instead of showing filtered on all the ports I stated before, now only two ports show up 443 and 8443 where 443 shows closed.  Much cleaner.  Now, check your port forwarding and make sure that you have 80 and 443 both open to your system at 192.168.1.222

Comment: @Terrance I posted my port forwarding table. Ports 80 and 443 should be open.

Comment: You need the same on  the internal ports as well.  80 external needs to go to port 80 internal then point to 192.168.1.222.  Do the same for 443.  I have made it a habit to do one port per entry.

Comment: @Terrance I still have a similar issue even after editing the port forwarding configuration. When I type in `scilabnet.asuscomm.com` I don't get the page, but when I type in the ip, it comes right up. How can I fix that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94106/discussion-between-terrance-and-sarah-szabo).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to reach scilabnet.asuscomm.com in my browser and it didn't respond (the domain name did resolve). That's almost certainly the reason certbot timed out. Find out why scilabnet.asuscomm.com isn't publicly accessible via HTTP on port 80, resolve the issue, and then try again and it should work.

Comment: Wow, that's really strange, I can reach scilabnet.asuscomm.com on my browser. I didn't just type the IP. Any ideas for where I should start looking?

Comment: I would start with verifying the router settings. From what I can see, your ISP does not seem to use CGNAT or similar, as nmap returns fingerprint of ASUS DD_WRT.

Comment: @vidarlo So.... given the updates to the question, do you have any ideas? I can access the website locally, but not on the network. The issue is strange.